# Как реализовать авторизацию через Keycloak в моем мобильном приложении на Flutter?(android)

Tags: flutter, dart, мобильная-разработка, keycloak

У меня уже есть сервер Keycloak, который успешно авторизует веб-версию приложения, но я начинающий разработчик и не знаком с процессом интеграции Keycloak в мобильное приложение. Какую библиотеку можно использовать? Думаю над openid_client, но не представляю как это реализовать. Не нашел нормальных учебных материалов. Буду благодарен за подробное руководство или советы по этой теме.